# Minecraft: give poison to a mob when blocking with a shield(1.17)

Tags: minecraft

So I want to make a data pack that gives mobs poison if I block the damage with a shield. So my question is, how can I detect if I blocked a mob with the shield and how can I give poison to this one mob. Is this even possible with a data pack, or do I have to make a mod for that?

I'm doing this in the version 1.17.1

Comment: are you working with bukkit or forge? and what have you tried so far?

Comment: i'm trying to make a datapack not a mod and i didn't try something so far because i can't figure out how to detect when you block damage from a mob with your shield